# How do I render different views of Navbar based on user authentication?

Tags: reactjs

I want to render a different piece of UI of the navigation bar whenever the user logs in or logs out. For instance, once the user logs out, the renderLoginLink should be called with Register and Login links on the nav, and vice versa. The problem here is that it only re-renders when I refresh the page. 
What should I do to address this issue? Below is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import './NavBar.css';
import TokenService from '../../services/token-service'
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'
import { faImage } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons"
import { faSearch } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons"

class NavBar extends Component {

    handleLogoutClick = () => {
        TokenService.clearAuthToken();

    }
    renderLogoutLink() { //when the user has already logged in
        return (
            <div className='Navbar_logged-in'>
                <Link to='/my-wall' >
                    My Wall
                </Link>
                {' '}
                <Link
                    onClick={this.handleLogoutClick}
                    to='/'>
                    Logout
                </Link>

            </div>
        )
    }
    renderLoginLink() { //when the user has not logged in
        return (
            <div className='Navbar__not-logged-in'>
                <Link to='/login'>
                    Login
                </Link>

                <Link to='/register'>
                    Register
                </Link>
            </div>
        )
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <nav className='navbar'>
                <h1>
                    <Link to='/'>
                        {' '}
                        <FontAwesomeIcon icon='faImage' />
                        Imagery
                    </Link>
                </h1>
                <div className="searchbox">
                    <input type="text" name="searchBar" placeholder="Search for an image" />
                    <span className="search__icon"> <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faSearch} /></span>
                </div>
                <Link to="/">
                    Home
                </Link>

                {TokenService.hasAuthToken()
                    ? this.renderLogoutLink()
                    : this.renderLoginLink()
                }

            </nav>
        );
    }
}

export default NavBar;
```

```
import config from '../config'

const TokenService = {
    saveAuthToken(token) {
        window.localStorage.setItem(config.TOKEN_KEY, token)
      },
      getAuthToken() {
        return window.localStorage.getItem(config.TOKEN_KEY)
      },
      clearAuthToken() {
        window.localStorage.removeItem(config.TOKEN_KEY)
      },
      hasAuthToken() {
        return !!TokenService.getAuthToken()
      },
}

export default TokenService;
```

Comment: `handleLogoutClick` and `clearAuthToken` got called, but you're not setting the local state to reflect the fact?  FYI, any time you're using authentication, it probably makes sense to use `redux`.

Comment: Will I be able to do it without redux?

Comment: Yes, you can.  I recommended `redux` because you may want to share "logged-in-ness" with other components in your app.  Without `redux`, only `NavBar` would be aware of your login info.  Maybe, in another part of your app, you're interested in checking whether or not your user is logged in.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have stored a logged in state true when user logged successfully.for example :

```
fetch().then(res => ...
localstorage.setItem("logged", true)
)
```

So now, in navbar code:

```
{localstorage.getItem("logged") === true ? <Link>logout</Link> : <Link>login</Link> }
```

Answer (score 0):

**TLDR:**  You need to use a local state or props in order to get your component to re-render.  Simply by calling `localStorage` will not trigger automatic re-render.

`react` components are re-rendered whenever there is a state change or if it receives new props.  For your purposes, I recommend using `react-redux` to achieve authentication.

```
// NavBar.jsx
export class NavBar extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    handleLogIn() {
        // maybe you called a backend service
        // ...
        const user = json.user;

        if(user) {
            TokenService.saveAuthToken(user.token);
            this.props.loginUser({name: user.name, token: user.token});
        }
    }

    handleLogOut() {
        // maybe you called a backend service to deactivate the token
        // ...
        TokenService.clearAuthToken();
        this.props.logoutUser();
    }

    render() {
        // the user and user token are exposted to you via props
        // through the use of redux
        const { user } = this.props;

        return(
            <div>
                { user && user.token ? "is logged in" : "is not logged in" }
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(NavBar);
```

The idea is to store your user info in a global data store.  That way, you have the authentication info, username, email, etc. perhaps to be used in all your components.

You'll need to do some heavy lifting in order to get `react-redux` to work.  Something like this below (warning, untested).

```
// actions/actiontypes.js
export const LOGIN_USER = "LOGIN_USER";
export const LOGOUT_USER = "LOGOUT_USER";

// actions/index.js
import {
    LOGIN_USER,
    LOGOUT_USER
} from '../actions/actiontypes.js';

export const loginUser = data => ({ type: LOGIN_USER, payload:  data});
export const logoutUser = () => ({ type: LOGOUT_USER, payload: null });

// reducers/user.js
const initialUserState = {
    user: {
        name: null,
        token: null
    }
}

export default function userReducer(state = initialUserState, action) {
    if(action.type === "LOGIN_USER") {
        const objChanged = {
            name: action.payload.name,
            token: action.payload.token
        };

        return { ...state, user: objChanged };
    } else if (action.type === "LOGOUT_USER") {
        return { ...state, user: { name: null, token: null } };
    } else {
        return state;
    }
}
```

Your actions and state mappings would look something like this.

```
// You need this to access the data store
import { connect } from "react-redux";

// You need this in order to update the data store
import * as Action from "../actions";

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
    return {
        user: state.user
    };
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, ownProps) => {
    return {
        loginUser: payload => dispatch(Action.loginUser(payload)),
        logoutUser: () => dispatch(Action.logoutUser())
    };
};
```

Comment: Yes that is better way. if know about redux.then it's super easy to manage whole application.